# Get data from columnized data with bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

i a have set of git data from a script:

```
objects=`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head`

echo "All sizes are in kB's. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file."

output="size,pack,SHA,location"
for y in $objects
do
    # extract the size in bytes
    size=$((`echo $y | cut -f 5 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the compressed size in bytes
    compressedSize=$((`echo $y | cut -f 6 -d ' '`/1024))
    # extract the SHA
    sha=`echo $y | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
    # find the objects location in the repository tree
    other=`git rev-list --all --objects | grep $sha`
    #lineBreak=`echo -e "\n"`
    output="${output}\n${size},${compressedSize},${other}"
done
```

to print that data it is columnized for better reading:

```
echo -e $output | column -t -s ', '
```

How can I access the location of the first row and save it to a variable ?
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
output="size,pack,SHA,location"
firstRowLocation=""
for y in $objects
   # ... snip ...
   output="${output}\n${size},${compressedSize},${other}"
   [ "$firstRowLocation" ] || firstRowLocation=$other
done
```

Comment: yeah that does it for me !! Thanks a lot ;)